# Changing prefix of PHP sessions (nginx, memcached)

Tags: php, session, nginx, memcached, fastcgi

I'm using memcached as my session handler in PHP.
I setup a second Wordpress instance on a new domain and now ALL vhosts start really slow (from 200ms to 8 seconds).

I have seperate document roots, databases,... but all domains share the same session namespace `memc.sess.key.<session_id>`, which is, I think, the issue for the latency.

How can I change the **prefix** for each  domain used in PHP session?

E.g.

```
memc.sess.domain1.key.<session_id>
memc.sess.domain2.key.<session_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the nginx config, I put:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE memcached.sess_prefix=memc.sess.domain1.key.;
```

This now seperates the sessions for each domain.

*The site is still slow :-(*

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the slowness:

```
giant:~# tail -f /var/log/php5-fpm.log
[04-May-2014 21:29:50] WARNING: [pool www]
    server reached pm.max_children setting (50), consider raising it
```

Adjusting the `pm_*` and server/process variables in the config helped and the site is now running again with blazing speed.